# realloc error reading file

Tags: c, realloc

I have problem with this code. Some times it runs perfectly but another times it stops before the last print with the error message: "Error in './ga': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f97d1304ac6".

I'm go crazy because I'm not use realloc()!

I suspect that there is somethink wrong in the file reding part, because this problem comes out when I add this part to the code (previously I set the data with other two arrays).

```
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits<double>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <utility>
//#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>    // std::lower_bound, std::find
#include <random>
#include <cmath> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision
#include <vector>       // std::vector

#define NUM_CITIES 14 

long size_pop;
long tot_elem;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    size_pop = atol(argv[1]);

    std::cout << size_pop << "\n";

    std::cout << "double: " << sizeof(double) << "\n";
    std::cout << "float: " << sizeof(float) << "\n";
    std::cout << "int: " << sizeof(int) << "\n";
    std::cout << "long: " << sizeof(long) << "\n";

    tot_elem = NUM_CITIES * size_pop;
    std::cout << "tot_elem: " << tot_elem << "\n";

    // std::cin.get() != '\n';

    struct timeval start, end, setup_start, setup_end, fitness_start, fitness_end, next_gen_start, next_gen_end, sort_start, sort_end;
    struct timeval fitness_total_start, fitness_total_end, probability_start, probability_end, selection_start, selection_end;
    struct timeval crossover_start, crossover_end, mutation_start, mutation_end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    std::vector<double> v_set;
    std::vector<double> v_fit;
    std::vector<double> v_sor;
    std::vector<double> v_sel;
    std::vector<double> v_cros;
    std::vector<double> v_mut;

    // coordinate delle città
    // int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    // int y[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    // città
    //city city_set[NUM_CITIES];
    int city_set_x[NUM_CITIES];
    int city_set_y[NUM_CITIES];
    int city_set_id[NUM_CITIES];

    // popolazione composta da path (possibii soluzioni al problema)
    int *city_x = (int *)malloc(tot_elem * sizeof(int));
    // memset(city_x, -1, tot_elem * sizeof(int));
    int *city_y = (int *)malloc(tot_elem * sizeof(int));
    // memset(city_y, -1, tot_elem * sizeof(int));
    int *city_id = (int *)malloc(tot_elem * sizeof(int));
    // memset(city_id, -1, tot_elem * sizeof(int));
    fit *fitness_element = (fit *)malloc(size_pop * sizeof(fit));

    // mating_pool, i migliori elementi della popolazione
    int *mating_x = (int *)malloc(NUM_CITIES * SIZE_MATING * sizeof(int));
    int *mating_y = (int *)malloc(NUM_CITIES * SIZE_MATING * sizeof(int));
    int *mating_id = (int *)malloc(NUM_CITIES * SIZE_MATING * sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));

    // std::cin.get() != '\n';
    std::cout << "read from file\n";

    // leggo le coordinate delle città
    const char *filename = "/home/davide/Documenti/GA/BURMA14.txt";

    char *line;
    size_t n = 5;

    FILE *coordFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    //FILE *f = fopen("/home/davide/Documenti/GA/result.txt", "w");

    int i; // indice dell'array
    int x, y; // coordinate delle città

    while(getline(&line, &n, coordFile) != -1 && i <= NUM_CITIES)
    {
        int items = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &i, &x, &y);
        if(items != 3)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        --i;
        //std::cout << x << "\n";
        //std::cout << y << "\n";
        //std::cout << i << "\n";

        city_set_x[i] = x;
        city_set_y[i] = y;
        city_set_id[i] = i;
    }
    fclose(coordFile);

    // std::cin.get() != '\n';


    // stampa
    std::cout << "[CITTA.X]\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES; ++i) {

        // city_set_x[i] = x[i];
        // city_set[i].x = i + 1;
        std::cout << city_set_x[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "[CITTA.Y]\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES; ++i) {

        // city_set_y[i] = y[i];
        // city_set[i].y = i + 1;
        std::cout << city_set_y[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "[CITTA.ID]\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES; ++i) {

        // city_set_id[i] = i;
        std::cout << city_set_id[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The file from I read is this.

```
1 16 96
2 16 94
3 20 92
4 22 93
5 25 97
6 22 96
7 20 97
8 17 96
9 16 97
10 14 98
11 16 97
12 21 95
13 19 97
14 20 94
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ code and not `new`?

Comment: Shall you swap C tag with C++? Because of the templates, namespaces...

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can catch the crash as it happens, and locate where in you code it occurs. Then you can also examine variables and their values, to see if they are all okay.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize local variables before you use them, or you will have *undefined behavior*. For example, you don't initialize `i` before you use it in a loop condition.

Comment: In your loop condition you test for `i <= NUM_CITIES` but inside the loop you read i from the file and call `--i` and then use it as index. You have to check i after the sscanf call instead of the loop condition.

Comment: What is `fit` type?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I know this. It's because into the file the id have that enumaration, but in the code I have to decrement it for correct indexing

Comment: The decrementing is not the problem. The problem is that you are using the index read from the file unchecked. For the code to be correct i, after decrement, must be < NUM_CITIES.  So when the next loop starts your check for `i <= NUM_CITIES` is pointless. If ever that fails then the harm is already done. And due to the decrement it should also be `i < NUM_CITIES`, putting a city 15 in the file will have undefined behavior but not trigger your check.

Comment: @purplepsycho it is for the rest of the code. I had reedit the code

Comment: What is `fit`in this line: `fit *fitness_element = (fit *)malloc(size_pop * sizeof(fit));`? And what is `SIZE_MATING`? Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: `char *line;
    size_t n = 5; ...
    while(getline(&line, &n, ...` --> `char *line = NULL;  size_t n = 0; ...`

Comment: Not a problem, but pointless:  `city_set_id[i] = i;`  There's no information saved by setting the `i`th element to `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
char *line;
size_t n = 5;
...
int i; // indice dell'array
...
while(getline(&line, &n, coordFile) != -1 && i <= NUM_CITIES)
{
    int items = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &i, &x, &y);
...
```

`line` is not initialized, and this almost certainly causes the reported `realloc()` error.

Per [the `getline()` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html):

> The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that
>   could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero, the
>   application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an object of
>   size at least `*n` bytes, or is a `null` pointer.

Note that `i` is also not initialized, and its value is not set until the `sscanf()` call immediately after the `while()` loop starts.  But `i` is used in the `while`-loop's conditional clause, potentially causing problems with loop control.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That too - but worst case that will just short-circuit the loop.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `i` is used in the loop condition `i <= NUM_CITIES` before the `sscanf()` call.  If it's some random value greater than `NUM_CITIES`, the loop won't run.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was limiting my answer to the `realloc()` error.

Comment: I removed my (now useless) comments.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You save my life. Thank you.